# javascript prototype logic

Tags: javascript

I'm reading [professional javascript for web developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764579088), and they present the following:

This code works:

```
var friend = new Person();

Person.prototype.sayHi = function(){
    alert("hi");
};

friend.sayHi();
```

but this code does not:

```
function Person(){
}

var friend = new Person();

Person.prototype= {
   constructor: Person,
   name: "Nicholas",
   age: 29,
   job: "Software Engineer",
   sayName: function () {
       alert(this.name);
   }
};

friend.sayName();
```

I get that, in the second example, the prototype is defined after the `friend` variable is instantiated, but in that case, why does the first example work?

Comment: I'm no expert at this - but are you allowed to completely overwrite the `property` object? I'd think you should create the variables you want in the object declaration, and then use `Person.prototype.sayName = function(){}` afterwards. I'm thinking that the `prototype` also contains various other Object-related things that you're removing by overwritting it completely in your second example.

Comment: In first sample you're adding a property to a prototype, in the second - overriding the whole prototype. The cases just not comparable. Change them to look alike and you'll get the same behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first snippet, you are adding to the existing prototype that has already been provided to the instance.  In the second, you are creating a new prototype for `Person`, which is different from the prototype object that has already been given to `friend`.

If you are adding new functions to the prototype, you can do it at any time before that function gets called.  Assigning a new object to the constructor function's prototype needs to be done before instantiating new instances.

Comment: additional question: if the prototype had not yet been defined in the first example, would it no longer work?

Comment: A default prototype gets constructed when you declare the function.